# I need to add a message box and e-mail textbox and display everything in my form in the msgresults tag

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to add a message box and e-mail textbox and display everything in my form in the 'msgresults' tag.

I need to add a Message box and and e-mail text box. Then I need all information to be shown within the MsgResults tag. The radioboxes already are shown this way.

```js
function validateForm(){
 var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
 var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
 if (name == "" || name == null){ 
  resultsMsg("We need your name please");
 }else{
  if(age == "" || name == null || isNaN(age)){
   resultsMsg("Please enter a number for your age");
  }else{
   if(!getSkill()){
    resultsMsg("Please select the type of problem you are having.");
   }else{
    resultsMsg("Type of Problem: " + getSkill());
   }//end else
  }// end function
 }
}
  function getSkill(){
   var isChecked = false;
   var theSelection;
   var skills = document.getElementsByName('skillset');
   for (var i=0; i < skills.length; i++){
    if(skills[i].checked){
     isChecked = true;
     theSelection = skills[i].value;
     break;
    }
   }
   if(isChecked){
    return theSelection;
   }else{
    return false;
   } // end else
 } // end function
  
 function resultsMsg(s){
  var resultsBox = document.getElementById("results");
  
  resultsBox.innerHTML=s;
 } // end function
```

```html
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
 <label>Full Name:
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
 </label>
 <br> <!-- new line here -->
  <label>Your Age: &nbsp;
  <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
 </label>
 <br> <!-- new line here -->
   <input type="radio" name="skillset" value="Technical Issues">Technical Issues</br>
 <input type="radio" name="skillset" value="Recovery Issues">Recovery Issues</br>
 <input type="radio" name="skillset" value="Hardware Issues">Hardware Issues</br>
 <input type="radio" name="skillset" value="Software Issues">Software Issues</br>
 <input type="radio" name="skillset" value="Software Crashes">Software Crashes</br>
 <input type="radio" name="skillset" value="Hardware Malfunctions">Hardware Malfunctions</br>
 <input type="radio" name="skillset" value="General Problems">General Problems</br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="validateForm();">&nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to add the given name and age to the result-div, on top of the 'Type of Problem' that is already show. That can be easily achieved by adding the correct variables to the last else-loop in your `validateForm` function. Something among the following should probably work:

```
resultsMsg("Name: "+name+ "<br>Age: " +age+ "<br>Type of Problem: " + getSkill());
```